# Cbind columns from lists with other list

Tags: r, list, cbind

I have a list call `Totalsamples`, inside the list I have 9 data frames that look like this:

```
year  total
2015   100
2016   115
2017   150
2018   155
```

I have other list call `counts`, inside the list I have 9 data frames that look like this:

```
year   A   B   C   Sum    
2015   15  10  5   30          
2016   10  13  12  35                   
2017   5   8   15  28             
2018   9   10  5   24
```

I want to add the column `Total` from the data frames on list `Totalsamples` , to the data frames on the list `counts`

So that I get this in every data frame from the list `counts`

```
year   A   B   C   Sum  Total   
2015   15  10  5   30    100      
2016   10  13  12  35    115                
2017   5   8   15  28    150         
2018   9   10  5   24    155
```

I tried this

```
counts<- lapply(counts, function (x) cbind(x, Total = Totalsamples[[x]][total]))
```

But I guess I'm indexing wrong the list `Totalsamples`. 
Can you tell me how to do it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Try `Map(merge, x = counts, y = Totalsamples, by = "year")` Consider to share a reproducible example if it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right you are indexing wrong. You are trying to index TotalSamples with the data.frame for counts.

Instead you can use one of these.

```
counts =  lapply(1:length(counts), function (i) cbind(counts[[i]], Total = Totalsamples[[i]][total]))
```

Or

```
for(i in 1:length(counts)){
  counts[[i]]$Total = Totalsamples[[i]]$total
}
```

Or you can:

```
counts = mapply(function(x, y) cbind(x, y[,-1]), counts, Totalsamples)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapply()`.

First, some sample data:

```
Totalsamples <- list(
    data.frame(year = 1990:2000, total = rpois(11, 100)),
    data.frame(year = 1990:2000, total = rpois(11, 100))
  )
counts <-list(
    data.frame(
      year = 1990:2000,
      a = rpois(11, 10),
      b = rpois(11, 20)),
    data.frame(
      year = 1990:2000,
      a = rpois(11, 10),
      b = rpois(11, 20)
    )
  )
```

Sum the columns in `counts`

```
counts <- lapply(counts, function(x) {
  x$sum <- rowSums(x[c("a", "b")])
  x
})
```

Now use `mapply()` to cbind. **Note:** this requires the row order to be the same in all data frames and the order of the data frames to be matching. i.e. it will cbind the first row of the first data.frame in Totalsamples with the first row of the first data.frame in counts, and so on...

```
mapply(function(x, y) {
  out <- cbind(x, y["total"])
  out
}, counts, Totalsamples, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```